# A/C only kicks on when set to defrost

Tags: ac, chrysler, town-and-country

07 Town & Country - The a/c compressor only kicks on when I have the it set on defrost. When I move the setting to vent or anything else it blows cold for about 3-5 mins then it gradually gets warmer and humid. Also, when it's on defrost blowing cold air, it feels like heat is blowing on the driver floor! HELP

Comment: Compressor is supposed to turn on automatically when you set it to defrost. Does it not turn on when you turn it on manually? Does it turn on, but warm air blows regardless of the temperature setting? It's difficult to understand your problem, please add more information.

Comment: Sorry to confuse u!

Comment: Can we see a photo of the control face in the dash?